# Javascript __doPostBack is freezing my browser?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, windows-server-2012

My code was working perfectly on Windows Server 2008. We have upgraded to Windows Server 2012 and now the same code is hanging my browser.

I assign:

```
writer.AddAttribute("onclick", "__doPostBack('CloseButton','" + this.ID + "')");
```

This will cause my page to reload and when it does I grab the Request["_*EVENTTARGET"] and Request["*_EVENTARGUMENT"]. No problems on Server 2008.

Like I said this worked no problem before but now when I click my close button the browser freezes completely (Windows Server 2012). If I try to navigate back to the domain through the URL I get nothing. If I navigate to a different domain through the URL the browser works fine. The only way to get back to the original domain is to close the browser and start again. Ctrl-F5 does nothing.

When I change the code to:

```
writer.AddAttribute("onclick", "__doPostBack()"); //No parameters
```

The postback fires, the page loads and Request["_*EVENTTARGET"] = undefined and Request["*_EVENTARGUMENT"] = undefined

Progress, but not what I need.

For whatever reason, as soon as I add parameters to the __doPostBack() function it freezes.

Like I said, this exact code worked on Server 2008 and is now broken on Server 2012. This has me stumped.

Thanks.

Comment: Any errors in event viewer or fiddler? Perhaps new IIS considers this unsafe operation

Comment: @Yuriy this wasn't the exact issue but it got me thinking. It turned out to be an issue with duplicate ID's on the page. Once I made my ID's unique it started working again. Bizaree because I am not sure why this exact same code worked on previous versions with the duplicate ID's?

Comment: @Hunter in fact shouldn't you be passing this.ClientID back, not this.ID.  ClientID is always unique.